# How do you escape quotes in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have issues with escaping quotes on my react app.

```
<textarea id="values" 
          placeholder="{ "name": "John", "test": true}" 
          onChange={this.handleChange2.bind(this)}>
</textarea>
```

I have tried to do this:

```
<textarea id="values"
          placeholder="{ \"name\": \"John\", \"test\": true}" 
          onChange={this.handleChange2.bind(this)}>
</textarea>
```

But that does not work for me.

Comment: It works if you put the string inside `{}`: `<textarea placeholder={"\"name\": \"John\", \"test\": true"} ></textarea>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using single quotes instead.

```
<textarea id="values" 
    placeholder='{ "name": "John", "test": true}'
    onChange={this.handleChange2.bind(this)}>
</textarea>
```

OR

move the quotes inside {}

```
<textarea id="values" 
    placeholder={"\"name\": \"John\", \"test\": true"}
    onChange={this.handleChange2.bind(this)}>
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<p>&quot;What if this? what if that?&quot;</p>

   "What if this? what if that?"
```